# Why js not working in cordova?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I'm trying to run this code in browser and in emulator, but js is not working.
In emulator sidebar does not open while in browser sidebar always opens.

How to fix this issue?

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/materialize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
    <title>App</title>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
  <nav class="blue lighten-1">
    <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed">
        <li class="bold"><a href="#!" class="waves-effect waves">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
        <li class="bold"><a href="#!" class="waves-effect waves">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="zmdi zmdi-menu"></i></a>
  </nav>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.button-collapse').sideNav();
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: No any errors in console.

Comment: Try inside document ready let's say: alert('testing'); and tell me if it works.

Comment: Please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pnia/xdrL9e83/

Comment: Alert not working.

Comment: I checked this, and my code working in jsfiddle too. I had tried=)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace your first meta tag with this meta tag.

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"/>
```

Comment: Such a line is so critical in cordova

Comment: This gives other problems. Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons' because it violates the following Content Security Policy.